# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.Devices.dll

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite

I'm referring this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted) to create a device identity. However, getting an exception as below:

[image]

Here is my config file:

[image]

Edit:
What is this Instrumentation key and value in App.Config? I just copied from the sample code. However, from where can I get it, in case I'm using a real device?

Am I missing any SDK or anything else? 
Do I need to download something extra? the tutorial does not suggest anything.
Even when I'm running sample code from GiTHub getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following screen snippet shows a reason of this error, such as *connectionString*.

[image: Error]

Use the connectionString from your Azure IoT Hub - see the tutorial section *Create an IoT Hub* step 6.

Comment: What is this Instrumentation key and value in App.Config? I just copied from the sample code. However, from where can I get it, in case I'm using a real device? I have edited my question.

Comment: You can delete them in the App.Config file. They are related with the Telemetry project and forgot them there.

Comment: Let me correct my previously comment. Leave them if you want to use an ApplicationInsights features - see the PromptText in the Telemetry.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the connection string you're using is in the correct format. It should look like:

```
"HostName={your hub name}.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={your key}"
```

You can copy the complete connection string from the portal as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolve: I was missing my connection string.Which I got from "IoTHubOwner" from Azure portal login. :)